# Having figures/images across different pages

Tags: graphics

I am starting from mid page a figure with multiple pictures going down the page vertically. How do I make the next row's image jump to the next page if there is not enough page space?

I'm trying to do something like this,

```
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[....]{First image}

%But 2nd image goes over the page and cannot be seen.

\includegraphics[....]{2nd image}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You might be interested in the `floatrow` package`.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I am all new to all of this and definitely will check them out :)

Comment: You don't HAVE to use a figure environment.  You can use \captionof{figure}{...} if needed.  The center environment might be useful, as it will break over pages.

Comment: as you have shown no source it is hard to tell you what to change, if you have a list of `\includegraphics{..}` separated by blank lines they will each form a paragraph and be split over as many pages as needed, just as paragraphs of text are.

Comment: I've edited my post, hope it is clear. If not, tell me please I would edit it again :)

Answer (score 1):

The extra space left over will usually go between paragraphs.  One can control is better by putting `\vspace*{\hfill}` anywhere you want the gap to be.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height=.6\textheight,width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}

\includegraphics[height=.6\textheight,width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

see, if the following solution is acceptable to you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[!b]
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[height=.5\textheight]{example-image-a}
\caption{sub figure a}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{my two part figure}
\label{fig:twopart}
\end{figure}
%
\begin{figure}[!t]
\ContinuedFloat
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[height=.5\textheight]{example-image-b}
\caption{sub figure b}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{my two part figure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2-6]
\end{document}
```

[image]